# How to access/disable the Google account sync settings in Android 8.1?

Tags: sync, 8.1-oreo

So I've just got a Nexus phone running Android 8.1 and wonder where I can turn off all of the Google account synchronization settings?
Under `Settings->Users & accounts->[name of google acct]` there's an option `Account sync` to `Sync on for all Items` - pushing it syncs all data. However, that's exactly the opposite of what I'm looking for. I'd like to disable all account synchronization. Do you have any ideas where the sync settings are hidden in 8.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You went a little too far! Go into settings -> users and accounts -> Google. Without pressing on your email address, you'll see an option "auto sync account data" turn that off. This will stop sync for all Google apps.

If you just want to turn off sync for some apps, then leave that setting on, and you'll have an option to choose individual settings.

[image]